# When using dm-cache, how do you do snapshots on a cached LV?

Tags: lvm, snapshot

In `dm-cache`, how do you make snapshots on a cached LV?

I tried the usual way on a CentOS 6.7 installation and got the following results:

```
# lvs
LV         VG          Attr       LSize   Pool          Origin             Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
LogVol00   vg_server17 -wi-ao---- 117.19g
LogVol01   vg_server17 -wi-ao----  78.12g
kvm163_img vg_server17 Cwi-aoC---   1.05t [DataLVcache] [kvm163_img_corig] 10.14  12.29           0.00

# lvcreate -s -n /dev/vg_server17/kvm163_img_snap -L 10G /dev/vg_server17/kvm163_img

  Snapshots of cache type volume vg_server17/kvm163_img is not supported.
```

Any advice?

Comment: I've got an answer for this from the linux-lvm mailing list: "Support for snapshot of cached LV is not yet written - so you need to uncache LV for now."

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround you could change your setup and use cached LVM volume (`/dev/vg_server17/kvm163_img` in your setup) as a PV for another VG where snapshots would work.

Have verified such setup on Debian Jessie. It works well, however, require  some changes to configuration.

To workaround duplicate PVs detected by LVM (cache origin and cached device have same LVM PV meta) update `/etc/lvm/lvm.conf`:

```
# Never scan LVM's own cache volumes. 
# Even if one of that would be identified as PV, most likely, use of cached non-origin is preferred.
global_filter = [ "r|^/dev/.*_corig$|", "r|^/dev/.*_cdata$|", "r|^/dev/.*_cmeta$|" ]
```

To workaround [bug](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=773731) with missing `/usr/sbin/cache_check` on reboot:

```
apt-get install thin-provisioning-tools
```